# JSONField doesn't allow null in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use a `JSONField` in Django, sometimes I need it be null so I defined it with `null=True, blank=True`, but when I'm validating with the Serializer I'm getting `my_data: [This field can't be null]`. Here is my code:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model): 
    my_data = models.JSONField('data', null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```

serializer.py

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    my_data = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
def save_my_data(self, request):
  info['my_data']  = None
  serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(data=info)     
  # validate the data
  print( serializer.is_valid() ) #returns False
  print( serializer.errors ) #returns my_data: [This field can't be null]
```

Any suggestions about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need `null=True`, since `None`/`null` is a valid JSON value...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `allow_null=True` in your serializer:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    my_data = serializers.JSONField(allow_null=True)
```

In DRF `allow_null` is `False` by default, even if your model is configured to accept `null`.